# Navigate to url from local page of a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension to stop myself from accessing certain pages too much, for example facebook. The idea is to have the extension blocks when I access facebook, but it still has an option for me to continue going to facebook.

Right now I'm using a background script to block it just fine.

```
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(e) {     
  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: 'waster.html'});
  });
  }, {url: [{hostSuffix: 'facebook.com'}]}
);
```

In `waster.html` I have a link to go to facebook. However, the issue is when I click that link, it trigger the same event again, then it gets blocked.

Is there anyway to workaround this? Like maybe pass parameter through the link to avoid blocking?

Thanks

==
Edit:
Add more details

The purpose is to block facebook.com, so I added a event listener to `onBeforeNavigate` with "facebook.com" in filter to stop the page before loading, to load my own page `waster.html`.
However in `waster.html` I want to have a link to allow users to go to facebook.

The issue comes from here, since when I click the link, it triggeers the event again, and well, blocks it again.

Comment: Simply check the current tab url `if (tab.url != chrome.runtime.getURL('waster.html'))` before `chrome.tabs.update`

Comment: I've just tried that out and it didn't work. The issue is, all those code will run once there's event of navigating to facebook only, so tab[0].url will always be "http://facebook.com".

Comment: Thanks for following up @wOxxOm. tab.url return undefined. It's an array.

Comment: I've just added in a bit more explanation at the end, not too sure if I make it more clear this time though :P

Comment: That doesn't seem to work actually. I've just messed around a bit, and not too sure why it's working now with a bit of check. Gonna put it in an answer for clarity but please do let me know if you can enlighten me on this. Thanks @wOxxOm

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: @Makyen sure, thanks for that. I'll add more info in then,

Answer (score 1):

I messed around a bit and it works now though I don't fully understand why yet

```
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(e) {     
  var url = new URL(e.url);
    if (url.hostname == 'facebook.com') {
        chrome.tabs.update(e.tabId, {url: 'waster.html'});  
    }
  }, {url: [{hostSuffix: 'facebook.com'}]}
);
```

And in `waster.html`, instead of normal link with `<a>`, I need to use following js:

```
$("#slack-time").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {
              chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: 'http://www.facebook.com'});
        });
})
```

Comment: I guess it works because `chrome.tabs.update` performs a certain navigation so only webNavigation.onCommitted is issued, not onBeforeNavigate. BTW, you can use chrome.tabs.getCurrent instead of chrome.tabs.query in this case.

Comment: Yeap, will update it to that. Thanks a lot for your help @wOxxOm